# Database data not accessing in views using spring data JPA with springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to display my database data using spring data JPA with springboot. The following is my code,
this is my controller file,

```
@Autowired
DriverRepository driverRepo;
@RequestMapping(value = "/dHome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public   ModelAndView driverLoad()
{
Driver driverDetails = new Driver();
driverDetails =  (Driver) driverRepo.findAll();
ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("driverhome");
return model;
}
```

And the following is my view file,

```
<c:forEach var="list" items="${driverDetails}">
<c:out value="${list.name}"/>
<c:out value="${list.age}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

And I am getting the result like 
"There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.central.model.Driver"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when you use findAll method, it returns List. 

List< Driver> driverDetails = new ArrayList< Driver>();
driverDetails =  (List< Driver>) driverRepo.findAll();

You also need to add driverDetails to model.addAttribute()
This should work. Do some research on how to send a model to a view using ModelAndView